Error: The input directory "/opt/chromium/chromium-v127.0.0-pack.tar" does not exist
I'm trying to extract a video list of a Tiktok profile with Puppeteer and Chromium, but my executable path can't be recognized. I don't know where the problem is, I also tried with some path similar to that one path, I also tried to extract the .tar but it doesn't work again
✓ Compiled /lib/api/scraper in 401ms (712 modules)
 ⨯ Error: The input directory "/opt/chromium/chromium-v127.0.0-pack.tar" does not exist.


export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const { siteUrl } = await request.json();
    await chromium.font(
        "https://raw.githack.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/master/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf"
    );

    const isLocal = process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: isLocal ? puppeteer.defaultArgs() : [...chromium.args, '--hide-scrollbars', '--incognito', '--no-sandbox'],
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH || await chromium.executablePath("/opt/chromium/chromium-v127.0.0-pack.tar"),
        headless: chromium.headless,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(siteUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


    const pageTitle = await page.title();

    const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" });
    await browser.close();

    console.log({ pageTitle }); // Esto imprime los resultados en la consola

    return Response.json({
        pageTitle,
        screenshot
    });
}


My directories
The problems comes when the path isn't wrong,i've tried with ;
("opt/chromium/")
("/opt/chromium/")
("../opt/chromium/")

